# How can I block USB port access with certain permissions on Sharepoint?

Tags: 2010, security

Is this at all possible?
I've been told to do it and do not know how.
I'm using Sharepoint 2010

Comment: Are you sure you are asking if using Permission in a SharePoint site the USB port access on a server/workstation can be blocked? If that is your question then Dennis has answered your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. Share point is not something that controls the PC environment.